# npm install Error: EACCES: permission denied

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I installed nvm , node and npm on to a new linux VM (debian 11 - bullseye)
When I do `which npm` , it shows

`/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v20.4.0/bin/npm`

I created a `test` directory in `/var`

and I ran `npm install --verbose @wordpress/scripts --save-dev` command from `/var/test` and got error

```
 Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/test/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/test/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/var/test/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
```

Then as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/how-to-fix-npm-throwing-error-without-sudo) , I did

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
export NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global
export PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin
echo -e "export NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global\nexport PATH=\$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
```

restarted terminal

and then tried `npm install --verbose @wordpress/scripts --save-dev` again but I  still get  `Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/test/node_modules'`

how can I run npm install from /var/test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must give write permission to this folder

```
sudo a+w /var/test
```

Comment: The command that I ran was `sudo chmod a+w /var/test`